# How to remove form errors after switching screens?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I am working on a contact form, when submitting an empty form the server sends a response with `error: "invalidData"` and I store an error message in Redux Store to later display it:

```
if (responseJSON.message == "invalidData") {
    dispatch(renderError("Invalid Data!"));
}
```

then I extract it in component as:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  formError: state.cForm.error,
});
```

and finally showing the error in contact screen after submitting the form as:

```
{formError && (
   <Text style={{ color: "#f00", textAlign: "left", alignSelf: "stretch" }}>
     {formError}
   </Text>
)}
```

The error shows with no problem, but when I leave the current contact screen and navigate to other screens and if I go back to the contact screen, the error is still there. How do I resolve this issue? Or just show the error for 30 seconds and then remove it.

Thanks you in advance for help.

Comment: For your consideration, you may choose to check whether the form is empty before the form submission. (basic validation).

Comment: Yes, current app is in its initial steps, I am thinking of doing that in next steps, for now I need to know how to handle errors coming from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can empty redux store when your component will unmounted or mounted (practically no difference).

So you have to make an action to empty formError in redux. e.g. `dispatch(removeError(""))`
and in componentWillUnmount or componentDidMount (or even useEffect in functional components) you must call it as below:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  dispatch(removeError(""))
}
```